# If I send some data then immediately close the socket, will the other end receive the data?

Tags: sockets

For .NET framework **System.Net.Sockets.Socket**, if I send some data then immediately close the socket, will the other end receive the data?

If not, is there a way for me to close the socket only after the other end receives the data?

Comment: Well I worked with Tcp sockets before. Tcp handle every send and receive acknowledged and if some bytes don't reach to destination, in lower layers of networks, resend will be handled until successful receive. On the other hand, Udp won't wait for acknowledged. I think that you have to right some sample codes and test it, and also take a look at protocols. In my experience when you closed socket, on the other side, get socket closed message.

Comment: But I first send some data, then close the socket. If the other end is able to receive the "socket closed" notification, wouldn't it have received the data before that?

Comment: No. In this way data fully received and socket will close after sending entire data.That situation will happen when sometimes sending long data and in middle of process network or internet will be closed.Remember Socket.send has a return value which show total bytes it sent. You can check it by real data length.Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebSocket` over `HTTP` works by establishing a `TCP/IP` connection, which requires the clients to sends an `upgrade` header in the payload to the server, and if the server can establish the create a `WebSocket` connection, it will reply with a `HTTP 101 Switching Protocols` response. Once the connection is established successfully, you can send data back and forth.

Interesting enough, requesting to close the connection also requires you to send a frame, which means you are also sending data to the server. Not even that, to properly close the connection, the sever also needs to respond with the same closing frame, once that happens the TCP connection is terminated and you can no longer send data.

What that means in your case is the server would receive the data you had sent before sending the close request frame.

You can read more about the details of frame, http headers, etc in the protocol RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455